# Angularfire2 auth subscription won't fire on mobile

Tags: ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have an ionic2 project with angularfire2 and firebase3. For reasons I have not been able to figure out this simple code just won't work on a mobile:

```
constructor(private af: AngularFire)
{
}

ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.af.auth.subscribe((auth) =>
    {
        console.log("auth fired");
    });
}
```

It compiles fine, the `ngAfterViewInit` fires but the subscription never fires.
I can login with email or via googleplus without problems (both use `Observables`) but the auth subscription won't fire.

When I run it in a desktop browser via `ionic serve` it works as it should. On a mobile device, however, it just won't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Facing similar issue! I am on angularfire2 beta 2 and angular2 rc3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue and after updating AngularFire2 to version beta 3, the issue got fixed.

So, in package.json, change as:

```
"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.3-0930330"
```

And then npm install and try running the application. npm install complained of unmet peer dependencies requiring Angular 2 RC 2, and I am using RC3. But it was just a warning, and the app runs fine after this change.

Comment: Where are you getting "3-0930330" from? Interested in how to get that specific of a version #.